# Add a ProgressBar into a custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I could not find tips or examples about how to do this. I want to add a progressbar over a Rect that I have already drawn, so how I can I do this?

Your answers will be truly appreciated! :)

**Edited**

```
public class MainView extends View {

    public MainView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MainView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        logo.set(getPX(5), getPX(10), getPX(65), getPX(70));

        background.set(getPX(30), getPX(2), canvas.getWidth() - getPX(10),
                getPX(81));

        canvas.drawRect(background, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(logo, paint);
    }

    final private int getPX(float dp) {
        return (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * dp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show code for your Rect

Comment: `progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(yourRect);`  //as i understand, you simply want to reposition your progress bar based on Rect coordinates

Comment: @MocialovBoris I have added it. Sorry about that, but I just thought it won't get a benefit whether it's added or not.

Comment: @MocialovBoris NO! I actually want to added (Or draw it) into my custom view.

Comment: `yourCustomView.addView(new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleSmall))`

Comment: @MocialovBoris I am sorry, but addView() method is not available in my custom view. How can I implement it? **I've updated the code with the entire class!**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32481/discussion-between-user222010-and-mocialov-boris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your implementation (as you shown it to me):

```
<ScrollView .. >
    <LinearLayout .. >
        <MainView .. />
        <MainView .. />
        <MainView .. />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

my proposed solution would be - extend your **CustomView** class with **LinearLayout** *(because then you can add additional views to your custom view)*:

```
public class MainView extends LinearLayout {
    private Rect logo;
    private Rect background;

    public MainView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setWillNotDraw(false);  //needed in order to call onDraw method

        logo = new Rect();
        background = new Rect();
    }

    public MainView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setWillNotDraw(false);

        logo = new Rect();
        background = new Rect();

        RelativeLayout progressBarLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true); //remove that (only for demonstration purposes)
        lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        progressBarLayout.addView(progressBar, lay);

        addView(progressBarLayout);

       //Apart from the ProgressBar you are able to add as many views as you want to your custom view and align them as you would like
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        logo.set(getPX(5), getPX(10), getPX(65), getPX(70));

        background.set(getPX(30), getPX(2), canvas.getWidth() - getPX(10),
                getPX(81));

        canvas.drawRect(background, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(logo, paint);
    }

    final private int getPX(float dp) {
        return (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * dp);
    }
}
```

> In this example I am only showing how to add ProgressBar component, because that was your original question

You will need to add some more code in order to carry out your requirements (got from questioner):
[image]

P.S. This is just a solution to your particular problem/request. I would advise to use ListView component, which is better in the sense that it reuses views, so in such cases where you will have *LOTS OF* custom view instances, your application might become unusable, because there will be too much load on the activity class.

In order for you to migrate to using **ListView** component, try some examples first, like [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just had to do the some code and a little bit changes to get work. Thanks again.